# Появляются странные рамки на мобильной версии сайта, если один блок полностью перекрывает другой, который с фоном

Tags: html, css

Пытаюсь адаптировать под мобильную версию сайт и заметил что при переходе на маленький экран начинают проявляться странные рамки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Добавил скрин с телефона (вид от основного сайта)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Добавил скриншот на котором отсутствует img, но проблема осталась

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался добавить "border: none;", но не помогло.
Вот пример фрагмента с багом:

```css
.sectionHeader {
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}

.newsColorLine {
    background-color: #000;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
}

h2 { 
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 27px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000;
    padding: 12px 20px 0 20px;
    background: #fff;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="sectionHeader">
  <div class="newsColorLine">
    <img src="./img/news/News.svg" alt="news">
    <h2>What’s new?</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Очевидно, что это стили от отсутствия картинки и скорее всего их рисует браузер. Как-то нужно с компа подключится к телефону, чтобы глядеть стили. Наверное. И это скорее всего тень .

Comment: обновил вопрос, добавил вид от телефона с нормальной картинкой

Answer (score 0):

Картинка тоже блочный элемент, <strike>inline-block</strike> и у неё тоже есть свои атрибуты и css (стили).

**Computed properties CHROME:**

```css
display     block
height      50px
width       48.8906px
```

По поводу `display: block` видимо в хроме, картинка совсем блок... Так-что и подавно получает все свойства блока из коробки.

```css
/** CSS */
IMG {
  /* свойства CSS для картинки? */
}
```

Comment: там скорее задний черный фон выделяется (который под перекрывающим его белым фоном). Убрал вообще блок с картинкой, проблема осталась (сейчас обновлю вопрос, добавлю скриншот)

Comment: @sazdan да, кстати очень возможно. Просто первое о чём я подумал, это о старых нокиях на симбиан ОС, там вместо VM использовался Renderer из ОС. Ох уж сколько больных тем в 2012м и.т.д. было по этой тематике... Горе боль и слёзы для вэб разработчика.